# Using Xpath to change innerHTML in Selenium; Python creates multiple escapes that lead to SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The script is as follows:

`script = "document.evaluate(\"(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]\", document).iterateNext().innerHTML = '<b>Test</b><br/><i>html</i>'"`

As you can see, I need to escape at least one of quotes, or apostrophes.

Other variant may be:

`script = 'document.evaluate("(.//*[@aria-label=\'Message Body\'])[2]", document).iterateNext().innerHTML = "<b>Test</b><br/><i>html</i>"'`

When used with `driver.execute_script(script)`, the text first gets its `\` escaped once, and following its execution inside Selenium code, it is getting escaped another time, leading to `\\\'` passed to the Java Script engine, which results in a `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error.

I tried with `r'test\''` but that ends up having much more escape characters.

Is there a way to pass that script correctly to the driver?

Comment: So many nested quotes can be a royal pain!  have you tried to get the script working directly in a browser's dev tool first?  That way you have something you know will work there, and that should make it easier to wrap it in either single or double quotes to pass to the driver.

Comment: Yes, I've started by created the function in Chrome dev tools first (that's even how I understood that I needed to use `.iterateNext()`.
The nested quotes have been a royal pain for some time, then I've found a workaround (see answer bellow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround.

I noticed that when using %r, the string was imported with its " " if the outer string is quoted with ', and imported with its ' ' if outer string is quoted with " ".

Example:

```
>>> "%r" % "test"
"'test'"
>>> "%r" % 'test'
"'test'"
>>> '%r' % "test"
"'test'"
>>> '%r' % 'test'
"'test'"
```

So I replaced the places where escape was needed by %r (without quotes), giving this result:

`script = "document.evaluate(%r, document).iterateNext().innerHTML = %r" % ("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]", "<b>Test</b><br/></i>test</i>")`

Witch gave exactly the expected result.

I hope this will help people with similar issues.